# Best secured method to store password to mail

Tags: php, security, imap

I'm making web app and I need to add simple email client like functionality. But this required to store password to clients accounts. What is the best secured method to store password or something else to allow client can check email inbox without repeating password after login to app. Like w can do it in gmail with pop3 account. Any idea? I want to do is in php.

Comment: This is what OAuth was built for.  For Gmail, this is the recommended way to proceed.  However, this can't be done securely in general.  You can encrypt the tokens, and keep the decryption key separate, but an attacker may still get access to both parts.  OAuth keys can at least be revoked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the email credentials of a user server side, this is a very bad idea. Sooner or later it will go wrong and you will have serious issues when their credential become public.

This is mostly because you need to store them in plaintext in order to replay them on the IMAP/POP server. You should have at least a very good statement in the TOS about that.

It would be much better to use oAuth or another similar mechanism which delegates the login to the target server. Many of the modern mail servers do have this now. You can have a look at how [Google does it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth).